# Jenkins "gulp serve &" not working

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jobs, devops

I just set up a Jenkins for a Web Application.
I build it with the next script :

```
gulp
gulp serve &
```

If I run the script without the "&", everything works fine - but the Job never ends(always listening).
If I run the script with the "&", I can't see any listening port, but the Job ends successfully.

Basically, I want to build the process in the background so the job can be finished, and another job will test it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try nohup:
`nohup gulp serve`

this will redirect the output to nohup.out in case you need the logs for later

Comment: Tried that and got an error message - "nohup: can't detach from console: No such file or directory"